# How to deal with JAXB.newInstance if I have a hierarchy?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, polymorphism

I have two following classes:

```
public class Solver implements FunctionI {
List<Double> pointsOfIntersectionX = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> pointsOfIntersectionY = new ArrayList<>();
..realization
```

and

```
public class PolinomialFunction implements FunctionI{
private List<Double> arrayX;
private List<Double> arrayY;
..realization
```

Realizations of this classes differs from each other so I can't make them as one.

Then I have following

```
public interface XMLinput {
 static void writeToXMLForFunction(PolinomialFunction pol, String fileName) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PolinomialFunction.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(pol, new File(fileName));
     System.out.println("XML");
}
static void writeToXMLForResult(Solver solver, String fileName) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Solver.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(solver, new File(fileName));
    System.out.println("XML");
}
```

This is the way how I dealt with my problem, but I wonder, can I make only one function which writes my classes(Solver/PolinomialFunction) into a XML file?
All my attempts like doing the following:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FunctionI.class);
```

or changing FunctionI to an abstract class instead of Interface and doing the same leads to error in this line. How can I deal with that?
**SOLVED**
Solution:
In the place of factual place of method call you have to pass Class object as parameter:

```
static void  writeToXML(FunctionI pol, String fileName, Class Tclass) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tclass);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(pol, new File(fileName));
     System.out.println("XML");
}
```

and factual place of method call

```
XMLinput.writeToXML(polinomialFunctionG, file.getCanonicalPath(), polinomialFunctionG.getClass());
```

Answer (score 3):

short answer: yes you can have one function.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PolinomialFunction.class,FunctionI.class);
```

But, it looks like there are some things you missed about JAXB... 
For the beginning :-) :

1. JAXBContext and its marshaller can handle any classes and hierarchies in them as long as they are known in JAXBContext (passed into `JAXBContext.newInstance` in different ways (one example is above, but you can pass package names as String if there are many JAXB classes in the package)
2. Create new instance of JAXBContext for every call is expensive operation - do it once outside of method and reuse it for marshallers. Marshaller is not thread safe, but create one is not expensive, so keep creating a new marshaller inside the method.

P.S. There is nothing about inheritance directly. JAXB manages by annotations in the classes (I do not see any in your example - do you have them?)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. According to your question: as far as I know I can marshall and unmarshall without annotations(as I did in my example, there is no annotations and it is working well). Also I have a question to your solution. What, if in the future I will have to work not only with PolinomialFunction, but with some other functions(e.g. LinearFunction). Should I modify my newInstance (add LinearFunction.class)? But what if I couldn't modify this for some reason? What do you think about my solution in my question section?

Comment: 1. yes you have to modify `newInstance` if you use array of classes in it (as in my answer). You may consider to put your classes into one package and then add new ones in the same package... you can make outside property  for what classes to put in it or do it in other ways. 2 about your solution - it is good if it is only about run program once for not big set of objects and it is not about parallel requests processing (like web service in app server). Otherwise performance is a big concern. New JAXBContext is very expensive operation especially when there are many classes to be registered

Comment: It is a common practice to create JAXBContext once and reuse it. As example for your case you can make a map of contexts per class, then you will create a new context only for first call for that class, then put it into map. Next time you will take a prepared context out of the map. Still if properties in your class is not that simple as `List<Double>`, but are nested objects - JAXBContext must have their classes registered.

Comment: ... I do not remember does JAXBContext traverses through all java referenced classes or not. You may test it if you need it...